# inlet velocity calculation from mass flow rate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

I am struggling for following calculation. Could somebody please help me with this?

Mass flow rate and inlet velocity at 300 K and 40 mbar are 4.246 g/min and 32.8 cm/s respectively, if the mixture contains 0.33 mol of 2-MTHF (100.116 g/mol molecular weight), 1.3767 mol of oxygen (32 g/mol molecular weight) and 0.5689 mol of AR (40 g/mol molecular weight) how to calculate the inlet velocity at 298 K and 1 atm.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hello, Sorry but this is not a homework question, I am repeating some simulations which are already published, and my code has some limitations and I need to give inlet velocity at room temperature and pressure I have already calculated but before carrying out simulations it is good to be sure that inputs are correct so I thought it is worth discussing here

Comment: Is the mass flow rate the same under the new conditions?

Comment: @RupaliTripathi: Take some time to read the links that JohnRennie provided, it will explain why we consider these types of questions to be homework for the purposes of this site.

Comment: @ChesterMiller  I do not think that mass flow rate will be same at both condition, it is given at 300 K and 40 mbar. But burner diameter is given 320 mm.

Comment: So what stays the same, and what is the new mass flow rate?

Comment: @ChesterMiller sorry I do not know if mass flow rate will be same or not that is what I want to know, if it is same I can calculate volumetric flow rate and then velocity. velocity = volumetric flow rate/Area this relation could be used but how to calculate at particular pressure and temperature that is another question.

Comment: Something involving flow has to be the same in the two situations.  Otherwise, in my judgment, the problem is not uniquely defined.